# linq.js unexpected results

Tags: javascript, json, linq.js

Okay, so I have got this JSON object called "Faults"

```
"Faults":[{"RoomId":1,"ElementId":173,"FaultTypeId":1,"Count":1,"Remark":""},{"RoomId":3,"ElementId":211,"FaultTypeId":7,"Count":1,"Remark":""},{"RoomId":4,"ElementId":173,"FaultTypeId":1,"Count":1,"Remark":""}]
```

Faults object shown in debugger:

[image: faults shown in debugger]

Now I need to check if a room contains a Fault by using he `RoomId`. 
The code I'm using for this is:

```
    Enumerable.From(audit.Rooms).ForEach(function(room, index) {//&radic;
    var containsFaults = '';

    //room.Id is ALWAYS filled, it can't be null
    var test1 = faults.Select("$.RoomId==" + room.Id).Count();
    var test2 = faults.Select("$.RoomId==" + room.Id);

    if (faults.Select("$.RoomId==" + room.Id).Count() > 0) {
        containsFaults = '√';
    }
```

But when I'm executing this code im getting the following results...

[image: result printscreen]

Why won't it just return the fault's from my object with the matching `RoomId`? I'm sure the Id's do match. What am I doing wrong here, i'm getting really stuck over this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and how should look like the result? only an array of `RoomId`?

Comment: I Just want the amount of faults per room, sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question

> Why won't it just return the fault's from my object with the matching RoomId? I'm sure the Id's do match. What am I doing wrong here, i'm getting really stuck over this...

You need to add `.ToArray()` to render the result.

```
var test2 = faults.Select("$.RoomId==" + room.Id).ToArray();
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var audit = { Faults: [{ RoomId: 42, ElementId: 4711, FaultTypeId: 0, Count: 0, Remark: "no fault" }, { RoomId: 1, ElementId: 173, FaultTypeId: 1, Count: 1, Remark: "" }, { RoomId: 3, ElementId: 211, FaultTypeId: 7, Count: 1, Remark: "" }, { RoomId: 4, ElementId: 173, FaultTypeId: 1, Count: 1, Remark: "" }] },
    roomId = 4,
    dataset = Enumerable.From(audit.Faults),
    test1 = dataset.Where("$.Count > 0 && $.RoomId==" + roomId).Count();
    test2 = dataset.Where("$.Count > 0 && $.RoomId==" + roomId).ToArray();

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! But I just want to know if the current room contains a fault.